# Multiple parameters in in Pipe using ngclass in angular

Tags: angular

I'm calling the pipe on li

```
 <li [ngClass]="time | style">
```

In Pipe using value as first parameter

```
 transform(value: any, args: any[]): any {
```

i want to pass second parameter also after time.

i tried to pass like this

```
 <li [ngClass]="time : secondparam | style"..
```

but this is not working

Any solution to fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: just pass like - `<li [ngClass]="time | style: args">`

Comment: @SonuSindhu time is also first argument

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve? Do you want to have an an additional parameter passed to your transform function or do you want a second value to be transformed?

Comment: here time is the first  and then the rest

Comment: if you have more then `time | style: second:third:forth` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass as many as parameters

`<li [ngClass]="time | style: args">`

if you have more then would be like

`<li [ngClass]="time | style: first:second:third">` and so on

Here is the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: If i have to check the results returned from pipe like this `<div *ngIf="time | checkpipe == 0">`

Comment: use like that - `<div *ngIf="(time | checkpipe) == 0">`